# Attaching to an object from another class?

Tags: java

I have a remote that I would like to attach to a switch in another class, but I don't know how to do it.

```
public class Remote {
boolean stateRemote;

public Remote()
{
    stateRemote = false;
}
public void attach(Switch aSwitch)
{

}
public void pressButton()
{
    if (stateRemote == false)
    {
    stateRemote = true; 
    }
    else if (stateRemote == true)
    {
        stateRemote = false;
    }
}
```

}

In the "public void attach" I do not know what to put.

This is the other class I was referring to earlier.

```
System.out.println("Testing Switch Methods\n_________________________________");
    System.out.println("Making a new Switch with the no constructor having no parameters");
    Switch aSwitch= new Switch();
    System.out.println("After construction, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());
    aSwitch.flip();
    System.out.println("After flipping, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());
    System.out.println("Making a new Switch with constructor having its parameter set to true");
    aSwitch= new Switch(true);
    System.out.println("After construction, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());
    aSwitch.flip();
    System.out.println("After flipping, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());

    System.out.println("\nTesting Plug Methods\n_________________________________");
    Plug aPlug = aSwitch.wherePlug();
    System.out.println("Switch is on? " + aSwitch.state() +
        " Plug is on? " + aPlug.state());
    aSwitch.flip();
    System.out.println("Switch is on? " + aSwitch.state() +
        " Plug is on? " + aPlug.state());

    System.out.println("\nTesting Lamp Methods\n_________________________________");
    Lamp aLamp = new Lamp();
    System.out.println("After construction, Lamp is on?: " + aLamp.state());
    aLamp.attach(aSwitch.wherePlug());
    System.out.println("After plugging, Lamp is on?: " + aLamp.state());

    System.out.println("\nTesting Remote Methods\n_________________________________");
    Remote aRemote = new Remote();
    aRemote.attach(aSwitch);
    System.out.println("Before pressing remote button");
    System.out.println("Switch on? " + aSwitch.state() + 
        " Plug on? " + aPlug.state());
    System.out.println("After pressing remote button");
    aRemote.pressButton();
    System.out.println("Switch on? " + aSwitch.state() + 
        " Plug on? " + aPlug.state());
```

Switch Class

```
public class Switch {
boolean stateSwitch;
Plug plug;
public Switch()
{
    stateSwitch = false;
    plug = new Plug(stateSwitch);
}
public Switch(boolean initialState)
{
    stateSwitch = initialState;
    plug = new Plug(stateSwitch);
}
public boolean state()
{
    return stateSwitch;
}

public void flip()
{
    stateSwitch = !stateSwitch;
    plug.flip();
}
public Plug wherePlug()
{
    return plug;
}


}
```

Plug Class

```
public class Plug {
boolean statePlug;
public Plug() 
{
    statePlug = false;
}

public boolean state() {
        return statePlug;
}
public Plug(boolean state)
{
    statePlug = state();
}
public void flip()
{
    statePlug = !statePlug;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attach"?

Comment: Your `pressButton` method can just be `stateRemote = !stateRemote;`.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to have a remote attached to a switch, which is attached to a plug, which is attached to a lamp.

Comment: @JClutch We need to see your code for the `Switch` class.

Comment: @snickers10m I editted in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

Add this to the top of your class:

```
//Add a field in your Remote class representing a Switch that your Remote can attach to  
Switch s;
```

Then in attach() add the lines

```
//Give our Remote a reference to the Switch provided as the argument when you call attach()
s=aSwitch; 
//Make the state of the Remote equal to the current state of the Switch
stateRemote = s.state();
```

Then in pressButton() add:

```
if(s != null) {
    // When we click the button we want the Switch to be flipped. However first we have to check that s != null to make sure that we are attached to a Switch.
    s.flip(); 
}
```

When we call pressButton() on the Remote, it calls flip() on the attached Switch. Therefore, the next time we check s.state() it will return the opposite of what it was before we pushed the button.

**To add the Plug:**

*In the Plug class*

Add a new constructor for plug

```
public Plug(boolean state) {
    statePlug = state;
}
```

add a flip() method

```
 public void flip() {
    statePlug = !statePlug;
}
```

*In the Switch class*

At the top of the Switch class add

```
//declare a field in Switch for the Plug
Plug p;
```

In both public Switch() and public Switch(boolean) add this line to the bottom:

```
//create a new instance of Plug that we will use with this Switch.
//make the initial state of the plug equal to the state of the Switch. 
p = new Plug(stateSwitch);
```

In wherePlug() put

```
//return the Plug we created
return p;
```

In flip() in the Switch class add

```
//flip the value of our Plug so that it equals the value of the Switch
p.flip();
```

I don't know if this is how you are supposed to locate the Plug for your assignment, but it will work with the testing code you provided.

Comment: Great answer! It'd be even better if you explained what's conceptually going on in this code. So write something like "when your button is attached to a switch, you'll need to store a reference to that switch in the button. You can do that by using a new variable." Etc.

Comment: @geokavel Hey, thanks for your help, can you explain the pressButton() section to me?

Comment: The explanation is especially important in cases like this where the asker is doing homework and we need them to understand what's wrong and how the fix works rather than just let us do their assignment free of learning.

Comment: OK, I added some explanations, let me know if you need any more.

Comment: @geokavel Wow, that was a great explanation, thanks. If possible can you look at the Switch class and look at the bottom with the wherePlug(), and help me with that? I don't know how to return the plug.

Comment: @geokavel Unfortunately, I tried something like that, but I am getting a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error at
            " Plug is on? " + aPlug.state()); in the main class.

Comment: Make sure you put `p = new Plug();` in both constructors of Switch, and that you put your `Plug p;` declaration right below `boolean stateSwitch;`. Also you have an error at the top of your Switch class. You should have a { not () after `public class Switch`.

Comment: You're welcome, just click on the check mark if you can. :)

Comment: @geokavel Sorry, but another difficulty has appeared, I need to make the plug always in the same state as the switch. Can you look at my plug class and explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Are you sure? I don't know if that makes sense. For instance you can have a lamp plugged in, but switched off. Just clarifying.

Comment: @geokavel In this case, the plug is suppose to have the same state of the switch. So in my above code, the plug is always set to true, but if the switch was false, then the plug should also be false.

Comment: @geokavel It doesn't work, as my plug is currently always set to true instead of the state of the switch. I think it's because the plugState is set to true in the public constructor, and in the boolean state, it returns the plugState which is always true.

Comment: Thats why i wrote to add a new constructor for Plug, and use that constructor.

Comment: @geokavel I did exactly as you did up there, but now my statePlug is always false even with the addition of the flip method.

Comment: did you add the line that says `p.flip()` to your Switch flip() code.

Comment: @geokavel Oops, forgot to add that, but now the states are reversed, when switch is on, plug is off and vice versa.

Comment: Make sure you add `p = new Plug(stateSwitch);` at the *last* line of *both* Switch constructors.

Comment: @geokavel Still the same result.

Comment: Can you update your code for Switch and Plug in the question, so I can see how it looks now?

Comment: @geokavel Updated the code into the question, it's near the bottom.

Comment: oh, i see, it's a very simple mistake. In your public Plug(boolean) constructor you want `statePlug = state;` not `statePlug = state();`. Otherwise, nice job on the code!

Comment: @geokavel Oh damn, that makes sense. I'm finally done, thank you so much for helping me with this. Sorry for taking so much of your time.

Comment: no problem, it's my choice to give you my time. Glad it's finally done, though!